# Why does namecoin have the redundant name_firstupdate step?

Tags: namecoin

I am trying to understand the namecoin protocol. As can be read in the [namecoin documentation](https://wiki.namecoin.org/index.php?title=Register_and_Configure_.bit_Domains), in order to register a domain, you need to execute the following steps:

1. Execute the command `name_new`, this pre-oders a domain name.
2. Execute the command `name_firstupdate`, this finalizes the registration, name becomes public.

Why does this second redundant step exist? Wouldn't it make more sense to merge these two commands, and enable users to finalize a registration by updating a domain directly when registering it with `name_new`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is to prevent *frontrunning*: When a victim registers `abc.com,` the attacker might notice the TXN with the `name_new abc.com` request on Namecoin's P2P network. Then, he might issue the same request but with a higher TXN fee, and "steal" the domain from the victim, who was trying to register.

The solution is simple:

1. Rather than sending `name_new abc.com` requests that reveal the domain, send a `name_new SHA256(r, 'abc.com')` request that *commits* to the domain without revealing it. This way, an attacker learns nothing about what domain is being registered.
2. Reveal the domain later using a `name_firstupdate r, abc.com` request which reveals the domain, preventing people from stealing it. By this point, the attacker can do nothing because `abc.com` has already been assigned ownership using the `name_new` request.